# Webpack compilation issue with sass template in vue single file component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-4, sass-loader, vue-loader

I am upgrading to webpack-4 from webpack 2.
It is breaking at places where my vue single file component has sass template in it.

It seems like sass loader is not coming into picture when file extension is vue.

I tried addidng sass as an extension in the webpack config, but it started treating vue files as sass files and compilation started breaking.

This is the generated error.
All the files having error have sass template in vue SFC.

```js
ERROR in ./public/vue/applicationform/Academic.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/Academic.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 51:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (51:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> #situation
|     font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
|     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Academic.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-135 1:151-154 1:156-288 1:156-288
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Academic.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/applicationform/Workex.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/Workex.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 715:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (715:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> #situation
|     font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
|     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Workex.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-133 1:149-152 1:154-284 1:154-284
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Workex.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/applicationform/Kra.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/Kra.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 73:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (73:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> #situation
|     font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
|     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Kra.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-130 1:146-149 1:151-278 1:151-278
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/Kra.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 1062:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1062:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> .passive-day
|     pointer-events: none;
| #app
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-130 1:146-149 1:151-278 1:151-278
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform/App.vue
 @ ./public/vue/applicationform.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/onboard/Onboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/onboard/Onboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 1065:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1065:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> .cov-datepicker:hover
|   border: 2px solid #d3d3d3 !important;
| .cov-datepicker:focus
 @ ./public/vue/onboard/Onboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-134 1:150-153 1:155-286 1:155-286
 @ ./public/vue/onboard/Onboard.vue
 @ ./public/vue/onboard.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/reconboard/RecOnboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/reconboard/RecOnboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=sass&) 1090:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1090:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> .class1
|   background-color: red;
| .class2
 @ ./public/vue/reconboard/RecOnboard.vue?vue&type=style&index=1&lang=sass& 1:0-137 1:153-156 1:158-292 1:158-292
 @ ./public/vue/reconboard/RecOnboard.vue
 @ ./public/vue/reconboard.js

ERROR in ./public/vue/console/Console.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./public/vue/console/Console.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&) 1787:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1787:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|
> .class1
|     border: solid !important
|     border-color: red !important
 @ ./public/vue/console/Console.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& 1:0-134 1:150-153 1:155-286 1:155-286
 @ ./public/vue/console/Console.vue
 @ ./public/vue/editp.js
```

This is my webpack configuration file

```js
module.exports = {
  mode : process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  context: __dirname + "/public/vue",
  
  entry: {kras: "./applicationform.js", edit: "./editp.js", reconboard: "./reconboard.js", jobpost: "./jobPost.js", register: "./register.js", 
      onboard: "./onboard.js", signin: "./signin.js", recdash : "./recDash.js", consent : "./consent.js", onboardconsent : "./onboardconsent.js",
      projectscreen: "./projectscreen.js" },

  plugins: [
   new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/dist']),
   new VueLoaderPlugin(),
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
   }),
  ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public/dist",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
    },
    module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.js$/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         options: {
      plugins : ['lodash'],
        }
       },
       {
     test: /\.pug$/,
     oneOf: [
         {
       resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
       use: ['pug-plain-loader']
      },

      {
       use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
      }
     ],
         exclude: /node_modules/
     },
    
       {
         test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
         loader: 'file-loader',
         options: {
           name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
         }
    },
    {
     test: /\.(scss|css)$/,

     oneOf: [
      {
       resourceQuery: /lang=sass/,
       use: [
       'vue-style-loader',
       'css-loader',
       'sass-loader',
       ]
      },
      {
       use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
       ]
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     test: /\.vue$/,
     loader : 'vue-loader',
     options : {
      loaders : {
        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
      }
     }
       },
     ]
 },
 resolve: {
  alias: {
   'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  },
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
  modules: [
   __dirname + '/public/vue',
   './node_modules'
  ]     
 },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    compress: true,
  port: 3000,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  hot: true
 },
 
 optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 30000,
      maxSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxInitialRequests: 3,
      automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
  },
  minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  }
}
```

This is my vue code

```js
<template lang="pug">
    
    // My pug Code over her
    
</template>

<script>
  // My script over here   
</script>

<style lang="sass">
    #app
        font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
        text-align: center
        color: #2c3e50
        margin-top: 60px

        h1, h2
            font-weight: normal

        ul
            list-style-type: none
            padding: 0

        li
            display: inline-block
            margin: 0 10px

        a
            color: #42b983

        .list-enter-active, .list-leave-active
            transition: all 1s

        .list-enter, .list-leave-to
            opacity: 0
            transform: translateY(30px)
</style>
```